# Site maintenance - Friday, January 13, 2023 @ 23:00 UTC (6:00 pm EST)

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance

UPDATE:  The maintenance window has closed. The network is no longer in read-only mode.

---

On Friday, January 13, 2023 at 23:00 UTC (6:00 pm EST), we will be conducting maintenance updates to our systems. During this process, we may experience some service or platform feature disruption. We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause. Should we experience downtime, we will resolve the situation as quickly as we can.

As always, we would like to thank you for your patience as we work hard on addressing these issues.

The duration of the maintenance window is Friday, January 13, 2023, from 23:00 - Saturday, January 14, 02:00 UTC (Friday, January 13, from 6:00 pm - 9:00 pm EST).

Comment: Is there any utility to the maintenance you feel comfortable disclosing? In other words, whatcha guys working on? ;)

Comment: @Spevacus just maintenance. The team chose a day and time when there is typically less activity so that if there is any platform disruption it should be minimal.

Comment: Never on a Friday??? Is it an emergency?

Comment: Oh dear, Friday 13th ...

Comment: Wow, you plan a scheduled maintenance and you manage to announce it one day ahead of time... Sorry you get to be the messenger @Rosie, but this is just very poor planning.

Comment: @Luuklag What, did you have some really critical StackExchanging to do tomorrow at 6:00 pm you can't reschedule without a week's notice?

Comment: @Luuklag sounds like it is not planned but response to some emergency. Otherwise there's zero logic in announcing "planned" maintenance few hours before it starts, and doing it during weekend when they're well aware that if something goes wrong, the whole site will be down for few days. In the past they **always** did it few days and even weeks ahead. The lack of transparency in the name of security (most likely) is annoying, but can't be avoided in big companies that don't want to lose money over panic of their users.

Comment: Come on folks, a plan doesn’t have to have been hatched weeks ago to be a plan. Unplanned would be the site going down by surprise. We discussed this maintenance all week, and decided yesterday when it would happen, and when we knew, we told you. I’m sorry but we can’t discuss details about the work until after it’s done.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Sorry, something important to do you can't reschedule with less than four day notice?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- personally no, but anyone living to the east from me is still within their business day.

Comment: I'm going for the 100 consecutive days badge on one of the sites I'm on. If I visit the site on the new day while it's in read-only mode, will it count the consecutive day?