# Site Maintenance - Friday, January 20, 2023 02:00 - 05:00 UTC (Thursday, Jan 19, 9 PM - Friday, Jan 20, 12 AM EST)

Tags: discussion, announcements, maintenance

UPDATE: The maintenance window has closed. The network is no longer in read-only mode. Thank you for your patience.

During our [January 13, 2023 maintenance window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385766/site-maintenance-friday-january-13-2023-2300-utc-600-pm-est), we determined that additional time is required to complete our maintenance but did not extend the window to avoid a longer site read-only period.

We will continue the work during a maintenance period this [Thursday, January 19, from 9:00 pm - Friday, January 20, 12:00 am EST (Friday, January 20, 02:00 - 05:00 UTC)](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingdetails.html?year=2023&month=1&day=20&hour=2&min=0&sec=0&p1=179&p2=24&p3=75&p4=224&p5=240). During this period, we may experience some service or platform feature disruption. We apologize for any inconvenience. Should we experience downtime, we will resolve the situation as quickly as we can.

We know millions of developers, like you, count on Stack Overflow to help solve the technical challenges you face, and we are grateful for your patience. Thank you.

Comment: Will this maintenance impact chat too? The previous maintenance period's banner indicated that chat would be affected, but it was not. Will that be the case this time?

Comment: "platform feature disruption" sounds like marketing version of "outage". This is your second attempt at this, so why does the [`@StackStatus`](https://twitter.com/stackstatus) Twitter account still have the last message from September 2022? | Maybe I don't understand the point of that account, but multiple times this year I have seen a banner where the first link pointed me there... it never lasted long, but still... why do you direct people there if you don't update (or even use) it?

Comment: @DanMašek: It seems https://www.stackstatus.net/ has a better history. However, the maintenance on 13th Jan., 2023 is not mentioned even there.

Comment: As a side-note, why is EST always mentioned? Is that because your offices are there?

Comment: https://hachyderm.io/@wrightfully/109716853847505633: FYI: For current status updates on #StackOverflow and the #StackExchange network, please visit https://www.stackstatus.net/

Note: We will no longer be publishing updates on twitter.com/@StackStatus

Comment: _We will no longer be publishing updates on twitter.com/@StackStatus_ - Why? Any meta post about it?

Comment: @Bacco We decided not to use Twitter for updates for this particular maintenance period, which is in keeping with the last couple of times we’ve done this. We have a Stack Status page, which is linked from the banner, and that will be updated throughout. We’re currently working on streamlining where and how we communicate about planned maintenance and unexpected outages. We are going to share an update on Meta once that is all finalized. We were able to remove the Twitter page  from the banner during this maintenance period to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Adriaan Probably because there's a lot of users in North and South America who are much more familiar with converting EST to their local timezone than they are with converting UTC to their local timezone. Personally, I feel that at least the banner should also state the time in the local timezone (i.e. the browser's timezone) and perhaps show a relative time (e.g. "in 1 hour").

Comment: @DavidPostill nice find, but who is John M. Wright, and how would anyone think to check his personal blog to see SE updates?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I happened to notice his post on Mastodon when browsing, His bio there says "Currently the tech lead on the team at Stack Overflow that focuses on the Collectives product."

Comment: There's a [DDoS attack underway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3AHj.jpg), that's why Stack Overflow loads so slowly, and why your first access after a period of inactivity is slow, while subsequent page loads are speedy.