# Tags linked in the site maintenance banner can be updated to avoid synonym tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, notification-bar, maintenance

During [Site Maintenance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385873/312043) there is a banner for read-only mode, which contains the following content.

> This site is currently in read-only mode. We’ll return with full functionality soon. Visit our status page or search [our recent meta posts on the topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+site-maintenance?tab=Newest) for more info.

The link referred to the following URL:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+site-maintenance?tab=Newest

The URL contains two tags, such as [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) and [site-maintenance](/questions/tagged/site-maintenance). But technically "site-maintenance" is a [synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/maintenance/synonyms) for the "maintenance" tag.
So, it results in the search result being "Tagged with [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) or [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance)".

I suggest changing the URL as follows; this will also result in the same search result:

> https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance?tab=Newest

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Maintenance tags]