# Why did the recent maintenance notices point to a search for [maintenance] or [maintenance]?

Tags: support, tags, search

The second link in these notices that were up today:

[image: "search our recent meta posts on the topic" link in read-only mode banner]

point to

```
 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+maintenance?tab=Newest
```

Why the duplicate:

```
[maintenance] or [maintenance]
```

[image: Tag search with both tags]

Comment: Better yet why does the interface reproduce the error with *"All questions Tagged with 'maintenance' or 'maintenance'"*?  Should be using a set not a list.

Comment: I ended up finding a duplicate after posting my answer here: [Tags linked in the site maintenance banner can be updated to avoid synonym tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385934/tags-linked-in-the-site-maintenance-banner-can-be-updated-to-avoid-synonym-tags)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you copy the link before clicking on it, you'll see it's actually a tag search for the tags [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance) and [site-maintenance](/questions/tagged/site-maintenance):

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maintenance+or+site-maintenance?tab=Newest
```

However, since October 30, 2021, [site-maintenance](/questions/tagged/site-maintenance) [has been a synonym](/tags/synonyms) of [maintenance](/questions/tagged/maintenance):

[image: Tag synonym page showing that the former tag is a synonym of the latter since October 30, 2021]

The banner link has apparently not been updated since the creation of the synonym, and needs to now be updated.

There should also be a couple additional changes to tag searching that should make this situation clearer:

1. Resolve duplicate tags and remove them from the search, so old links to a multi-tag search where one of them has been synonymized to another will only search for the one master tag.
2. If in a tag search the user searches for a synonym tag, add a notice that the tag has been swapped as it's a synonym, rather than just having it unexpectedly change.